# Value picker get items from a view with multiple values as separate entries

Tags: xpages, picker

I got a view with departments and the corresponding head of this department. Some of those bosses have more than one department, so I use the "Show multiple values as separate entries" in my view.

[image]

But when I want to use a value picker in my XPage using this view, I get square brackets for all bosses who head more than one department:

[image]

How can I remove those brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xe:simpleValuePicker` instead of `xe:dominoViewValuePicker`.

```
<xe:this.dataProvider>
    <xe:simpleValuePicker>
        <xe:this.valueList><![CDATA[#{javascript:@DbColumn("","YourViewName","YourColumnName")}]]></xe:this.valueList>
    </xe:simpleValuePicker>
</xe:this.dataProvider>
```

Seems to be a bug in `xe:dominoViewValuePicker`, had the same square brackets in my example. But using `xe:simpleValuePicker` is simple too as you have to write only this one line of code `@DbColumn(...`.

Comment: By using the simpleValuePicker and the DbColumn I can not longer open the page. My Code: <br/> 

    <xe:valuePicker id="valuePicker1" for="HasAsChef"> 
    <xe:this.dataProvider>
    <xe:simpleValuePicker>
    <xe:this.valueList><![CDATA[#{javascript:@DbColumn("","$xpPersonByOrgKzChefSXP",1)}]]> 
</xe:this.valueList>      </xe:simpleValuePicker>
</xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:valuePicker>

The error I get: <br/>
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.ibm.jscript.std.ErrorObject$TypeErrorObject
com.ibm.jscript.std.ErrorObject$TypeErrorObject

Comment: Your example does work for me. The error must be somewhere else. NotSerializableException sounds like a used java class which has not implemented Serializable. Can you separate this code in a new XPage and test it there?

Comment: Ok yes it works in an empty XPage once. But as soon as I open my XPage I get this error and then even the empty XPage doesn't work anymore... I don't know why. But thanks for your help!

Comment: Please remove this `dataProvider` part from your XPages and see if it works then. Look at YourServer\data\domino\workspace\logs\error-log-0.xml to get more precise information about the error.